# Clearpath Husky A200 model in gazebo - wrong turnspeed?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community!

I have a question concerning the clearpath husky A200 gazebo model. I set up a simulation for our husky in gazebo. After I got it running, I was able to control the husky model the same way as our "real" husky, running the same nodes in the simulation as on the real husky.

But there is a strange behaviour in gazebo during steering the model. It seems as if the steering/turning speed in gazebo is very slow compared to the "real" husky.

To get some numbers, I ran the "robot_pose_ekf" package to see some odometry data in rviz. When moving forward and backward on a strait line the data seems to be OK, but the turning speed is very different. For example, a 360° spot turn in gazebo are nearly 1080° in RVIZ regarding the odometry data.

Does anyone have some experience with this issue?

Regards
psei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73669/clearpath-husky-a200-model-in-gazebo---wrong-turnspeed?/) by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2013-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmukherj](https://answers.ros.org/users/3147/pmukherj/) on 2013-08-21**:
Hello!
This maybe because the "real" husky is running in open loop mode while the simulated one is not. I can verify this but just so I understand the problem well. I am assuming the "real" husky has an IMU? So the 1080 degree you turn you saw in rviz is something you observed physically as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A bugfix has been released to the ROS repo and should be available via apt-get in a week or so.

In the mean time, please check out https://github.com/husky/husky_simulator.git for the fixed version.

---

Originally posted by [yanma](https://answers.ros.org/users/5081/yanma/) with karma: 16 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems as if this problem came from a bug in the husky-gazebo plugin. Clearpath Robotics managed to send me an update of the plugin and now everything works fine.

---

Originally posted by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) with karma: 318 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1